# Rails 3 - Allow edit without update?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, edit, anonymous-users

Here's the situation:

I have a Rails 3 app that let's users add tags to a model (entry). However I haven't figured out how to allow users (all anonymous) to just view and add new tags without editing the existing ones. I'm not using any plugin like acts_as_taggable, I'm just using an association.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into having a new action for the Tag class?